# PHP password_hash causing problems

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, passwords

I'm gathering data from a form using POST method and when the data is entered in to the form and submitted, the data is added to the database correctly.

If I run it as below, I don't receive an alert when it has executed but the data gets correctly inserted in to the database.

If I remove the password hashing and add a password manually in to the query, it will still enter the data in to the database correctly AND give me an alert to tell me it has compelted.

I can't figure out why it will alert me without the password_hash but won't when it is included. Even though the data gets stored in the database correctly on both.

The code to pass the data from the form is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/accountcreate.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(".register-form").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
            
        $option = data.output;
                    
        if($option == 1)    {
            alert("An account already exists with the email address "+ data.message +" please login to your account.");
        }
        else if($option == 2)   {
            alert(data.message);
        }
        else if($option == 3)   {
            alert(data.message);
        }                   
    }
});
```

The code I'm using to process the data and store it in the database (minus the checks if an email already exists) is:

```
<?php
    
        else    {
            //Account doesn't exist - lets create one
            
            $firstname      = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
            $lastname       = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
            $dob            = $_POST['dob-reg'];
            $userpass       = $_POST['passwordreg'];
            $hashed_pass    = password_hash($userpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            
            $query  = $connect -> prepare("INSERT INTO `Accounts` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `DoB`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        
            $query -> bind_param("sssss", $firstname, $lastname, $dob, $email, $hashed_pass);
            $query -> execute();
            
            if($query -> affected_rows === 0)   {
                
                $connect -> close();
                echo json_encode(array( "output" => "2",
                                "message" => "An error occured."));
                return;
            }
            else    {
                //Data successfully inserted in to the database
                $connect -> close();
                echo json_encode(array( "output" => "3",
                                "message" => "$email")); 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: 1. Make the post manually and observe the response. 2, Make sure `display_errors` is on and `error_reporting` is turned up. 3. [Turn on exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) and enclose the DB code in a try/catch.

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to see the raw response to the AJAX query.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it's helped me resolve the issue now.